# Use of const, get paremeter NOT by-copy

Tags: c++

I wrote this code:

```
class Address{

  private:
    std::string street;
    int house;

  public:
    Address(std::string s, int h):
      street(s), house(h) {}

    void setHouse(int h) {house = h;}

    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream& os, Address &a);
};

class Person{

    private:
      std::string name;
      Address A;

    public:
      Person(std::string n, std::string v, int c) :
        name(n), A(v, c) {}

      Address& getAddress(){return A;}

    friend std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream& os, Person &a);

};

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream& os, Address &a){

  return os << "[" << a.street << ", " << a.house << "]";
}

std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream& os, Person &p){

  return os << p.name << " " << p.A;
}

int main(){

  Person pietro("Pietro", "Champs Elysees", 16);

  std::cout << pietro << std::endl;

  Address ma = pietro.getAddress();
  ma.setHouse(333); 

  std::cout << pietro << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I have these questions:

1. Why does the line `ma.setHouse(333);` does not have any side effect on `pietro` (ie in the second print the house-number is not changed)?
2. (I know that it's not the right way, but) how can i make `ma.setHouse(333);` having side effects on `pietro` ?
3. Why should i write `const Address& getAddress() const {return A;}` if the above code does not have side effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1. Because you are acting on a **copy** of `pietro`'s `Address`:

```
Address ma = pietro.getAddress(); // ma is a copy of pietro's address
ma.setHouse(333);                 // modify copy, not pietro
```

Q2. Take a reference?

```
Address& ma = pietro.getAddress(); // ma is a reference to pietro's Address.
ma.setHouse(333);                  // modifies pietro's Address
```

Q3. So you can have const correctness. Without the const method and const return value, you **can** affect the internals of the object. Furthermore, you cannot call the method on const instances or references.

```
const Address& ma = pietro.getAddress(); // Calls const method. Cannot modify pietro
Address& ma = pietro.getAddress(); // calls non-const method. Can modify pietro
```

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the line ma.setHouse(333); does not have any side effect on
>   pietro (ie in the second print the house-number is not changed)?

```
  Address ma = pietro.getAddress();
  ma.setHouse(333);
```

Create object ma and copy initialize it from `pietro.getAddress()`, so, `ma` has no any relation to `pietro` object.

> (I know that it's not the right way, but) how can i make
>   ma.setHouse(333); having side effects on pietro ?

```
Address& ma = pietro.getAddress();
```

> Why should i write const Address& getAddress() const {return A;} if
>   the above code does not have side effects?

You should make your function const - right, but return `const-reference` is not very good idea in most cases.